# A Grandma Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

This is my first question, let's hope it's not that simple!

> What is the fool who dresses as much as possible in summer and lets their clothes fall in winter?

**What am I?**

Comment: edited title to be more concise, hope you dont mind ;) nice first puzzle +1!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is

> A tree

Explanation

> It grows its leaves in the summer and shed them by winter.